# setting primary and subsequent groups for a user

Tags: linux, permissions

I had bob attached to a lot of different groups, he is my test dummy, now I am setting bob to a primary group called ftptest, and a few other secondary groups.

I issued this command `cat group` and see that bob is no listed on the ftptest group, but when issuing the -g to set primary group again, system tells me no changes made, even though bob does not show up.

I have not logged out and in again.

setting ftptest primary group to bob

```
ftptest:x:1002:bob,userx
userx@voided1.what~/Ubuntu>> su
Password: 
# usermod -g ftptest bob
# cat /etc/group
 ftptest:x:1002:bob,userx
```

setting secondary groups to bob

```
# usermod -G bob,users bob
# cat /etc/group
  ftptest:x:1002:userx
```

confuses me because bob is no longer on ftptest group, so I issue primary group again, and get this message.

```
# usermod -g ftptest bob
  usermod: no changes
```

I've logged out and back in with both users I have in my system. The one I made the changes in, and bobs account and still do not see bobs name along side the primary group.

```
userx@voided1.what~>> cat /etc/group
ftptest:x:1002:userx
```

but,

```
userx@voided1.what~>> groups bob
bob : ftptest users bob
```

shouldn't cat /etc/group show bob belonging to ftptest?

Answer (score 0):

A user's primary group is stored in /etc/passwd.  If you check for bob's account in /etc/passwd you'll get something similar to this:

```
$ grep ^bob: /etc/passwd
bob:x:1001:1002:Bob:/home/bob:/bin/bash
```

The fields, from left to right, are:

- username
- password placeholder (modern systems just put an x here)
- numeric UID
- numeric GID (primary group)
- comment field (human readable name)
- home directory
- default shell

The group field should show 1002, which is the ftptest GID.

The /etc/group file contains secondary groups.  Oftentimes I will see a user's primary group also listed in the /etc/group, meaning that it is defined both as a primary and as a secondary group, but this isn't always the case.  As you pointed out, using the `group` command will list all the groups, and is a good way to see all the groups a user belongs to.